# Como gravar o resultado intermediário de um loop for em matriz, a cada iteração?

Tags: matlab

abaixo segue a tentativa de um código para calcular a seguinte situação:

- tenho dois vetores: "q_qp" e "pe", preciso que cada elemento do vetor "pe" multiplique todos elementos de "q_qp", por exemplo: o valor 9.528007810207796E-5 de "pe" multiplica todos os valores de "q_qp" e me retorna um vetor resultante na mesma dimensão de "q_qp" (33 x 1), e assim sucessivamente até o último valor de "pe".

Como a dimensão de "pe" é 22 x 1 e "q_qp" é 33 x 1, eu terei 22 vetores coluna de 33 linhas ao final do loop.

A questão é, como eu posso fazer para que a cada iteração o resultado seja gravado de forma ordenada em uma matriz de zeros com dimensão de 33 x 22, ou seja primeira iteração gravo o vetor na primeira coluna, segunda iteração gravo o vetor na segunda coluna, e assim sucessivamente. Estou usando o scilab e consegui gerar os vetores com o loop, porém não consigo de forma alguma gravar o resultado na matriz. Se alguém puder me ajudar, ficarei muito agradecido.

```
clc
clear

q_qp= [0 0.03 0.1 0.19 0.31 0.47 0.66 0.82 0.93 0.99 1 0.99 0.93 0.86 0.78 0.68 0.56 0.46 0.39 0.33 0.28 0.207 0.147 0.107 0.077 0.055 0.04 0.029 0.021 0.015 0.011 0.005 0]' 

pe= [9.528007810207796E-5
0.015612153888687455
0.04127114106369897
0.06865675895676779
0.10234219137829395
0.149156938574736
0.2221660433295402
0.3516835634365342
0.6253621948431046
0.9021458528207191
2.49812553600102
1.4110166279515943
0.47462270737544116
0.2936798150556328
0.2010333119231717
0.1471011647128549
0.1128517315033946
0.08968709798222249
0.07325270551003342
0.06114745114515898
0.0]

[l c]= size(pe)
Q1= zeros(33, l)
[la ca]= size(Q1)

for i= 1:l
    for j= 1:c

        a= pe(i ,1)
        disp(a)
        Q= a .* q_qp
        disp(Q)
        B(i)= [Q(i)] ***>>> Aqui eu gostaria que B recebesse o cálculo da primeira iteração na primeira coluna da matriz, na segunda iteração o vetor fosse gravado na segunda coluna da matriz B, e assim sucessivamente até completar o for.*** 
    end

    for m= 1:la  ***>>> esse segundo for foi uma tentativa de gravar os vetores na matriz, mas não deu certo. ele grava somente o resultado da última iteração, ou seja a multiplicação entre o último valor de "pe" e o vetor "q_qp".*** 
        for n= 1:ca
            Q2(m, n)= [Q(i)] 
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Está inviável ler sua pergunta, você poderia formatá-la melhor. Tem todas as opções em cima do editor.

Comment: Cara, a lógica para isso é simples, não entendo essa linguagem. Sendo qtd1 e qtd2 a quantidade de termos da matriz 1 e da matriz 2: for (int n=0; n<qtd1; n++) {

  for (int k=0; k<qtd2; k++) {

  matriz_r[$n][$k] = matriz1[$n]*matriz2[$k];

  }
}

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário amigo, porém, a linguagem do scilab não aceita esta lógica.

Answer (score 1):

Em MatLab usa-se a seguinte sintaxe (**imagino que em scilab não deva ser muito diferente**):

```
outputMatrix = zeros(33, 22);
for i = 1:22
    scaledVector = pe(i)*q_qp;
    outputMatrix(:, i) = scaledVector';
end
```

Observe que ao usou-se um vetor scaledVector como passo intermediário para transpor o resultado. Caso isso não fosse feito, geraria um erro de compatibilidade de dimensão. Mas este passo pode ser suprimido se a linguagem aceitar diretamente o comando `outputMatrix(:, i) = pe(i)*q_qp'`.

Comment: Obrigado por responder, porém quando insiro este código tenho o seguinte erro: Submatriz definida incorretamente.
at line      35 of exec file called by :

Comment: Estive pensando, se eu conseguisse fazer com que a cada iteração de "i" o vetor gerado pelo produto de "i" por "q_qp" fosse salvo em uma variável, ficaria mais fácil tentar uma solução. Teria como criar uma nova variável e dar valor a ela a cada iteração ?  Obrigado.

Comment: Na verdade é exatamente isso que o scaledVector é, uma nova variável. Não sei exatamente em que ponto o erro que está ocorrendo, mas acho que você deveria testar coisas como declarar o scaledVector antes do `for` e testar coisas novas no índice como:

    `outputMatrix = zeros(33, 22);`
    `scaledVector = zeros(1, 33);`

    `for i = 1:22`,
        `scaledVector(1, :) = pe(i)*q_qp;`
        `outputMatrix(:, i) = scaledVector';`
    `end`.

Comment: Obrigado por responder, vou tentar aqui, assim que tiver respostas posto no site.